# Setting focus on top nav and side nav at the same time (angular2+)

Tags: angular, navigation, navbar, angular-routing

I have a top nav bar, and a side nav bar in my application.

topNav.Component.html:

```
<nav id="topnav">
 <div class="container">
        <a  routerLinkActive="active" tabindex="1" class="skip-link" href="#skipContent">Skip to content</a> 
        <a routerLinkActive="active" tabindex="2" routerLink="/page1a">Page1-a</a>
        <a routerLinkActive="active" tabindex="2" routerLink="/page1b">Page1-b</a>
        <a routerLinkActive="active" tabindex="2" routerLink="/page1c">Page1-c</a>
 </div>
<nav>
```

topNav.Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-topNav',
  templateUrl: './topNav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topNav.component.scss']
})
export class topNavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

leftNav.component.html:

```
<nav id="main-navigation">

 <div *ngIf="section == 'home'; else homeInactive">
  <a id="Home" routerLinkActive="inactive"
    routerLink="/page1a"> 
  </a>
 </div>

<ng-template #homeInactive> 
  <a id="Home"
    routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/page1a"> 
  </a> 
</ng-template>

 <a id="leftTab2" routerLinkActive="inactive"
  routerLink="/leftTab2"> 
 </a> 

 <a id="leftTab3" routerLinkActive="inactive" routerLink="/leftTab3"> 
 </a> 
</nav>
```

leftNav.component.ts: 
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-leftNav',
  templateUrl: './leftNav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leftNav.component.scss']
})
export class leftNavComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() section: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I would like the "home" tab on the left Nav to stay active (or have CSS that makes it look active) while on Page1a, Page1b, or Page1C.

I would also like (upon page load), for "home" tab to be active in left nav, and Page1a to be active. I have tried templating in the Page1a html as a starting point, but did not see any results.

- All of these pages are individually routed and are not children of other pages* 
  Thanks!

Comment: You can use [ngClass]="{'active',variable==1}" instead of routerLinkActive (and manually change the value of "variable")

Comment: @Eliseo does 1 mean it is active and 0 inactive? So in the TS file of every top nav page, I would set variable to either 1 or 0?

Comment: It's an old link, but show the different uses of ngClass and style https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-classes-with-ngclass-and-ngstyle